# How to handle brush on left click and zoom on middle click in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, zooming, brush

I am trying to handle left and right click events differently on a line graph.

Left click should handle the brush behaviour and the middle click should handle the zoom behaviour.

I found Mikes example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6140181 how to block right click for zooming.

This works, but if I try to block the brush behaviour for middle clicks it does not work.

I also found http://wrobstory.github.io/2013/11/D3-brush-and-tooltip.html that creates new events and redirects it to other elements but I could not make it work to redirect the caught events to the zoom element.

Here is what I tried.
http://bl.ocks.org/bobatsar/9403d59b12e33a0925cb

Brush works with left click, but middle click should only zoom and not change the brush.
Mousewheel zooming is also ok because brushing does not catch the mousemove.

If I click on the line with a middle click only zooming is activated and not brushing. This is what I want for the whole graph.

Is it possible to check in the brushstart and/or zoomstart eventhandler if the click was left/middle and abort the zoom/brush event if it does not match but let the events propagate to other elements?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds as if you would need to change the implementations of the brush and zoom behaviours.

Comment: So you mean there isn't a way to solve this problem as it is implemented now in d3.js?

Comment: Not with just D3 as far as I can see. What I would do is have a container that covers everything and receives all the events. The handler for this container would then dispatch/transform these events to the other element.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try that. But I am now two weeks off. Afterwards I'll come back with my results.